# fileinfo and mime types I've never heard of

Tags: php, fileinfo

I'm not a stranger to mime types but this is strange. Normally, a text file would have been considered to be of text/plain mime but now, after implementing fileinfo, this type of file is now considered to be "text/x-pascal". I'm a little concerned because I need to be sure that I get the correct mime types set before allowing users to upload with it.

Is there a cheat sheet that will give me all of the "common" mimes as they are interpreted by fileinfo?

---

Sinan provided a link that lists all of the more common mimes. If you look at this list, you will see that a .txt file is of text/plain mime but in my case, a plain-jane text file is interpreted as text/pascal.

Answer (score 4):

`fileinfo` is a "best guess". It analyzes only a portion of the file in order to try to figure out what type the file is, and as such it can be fooled easily enough. Perhaps your file starts with a Pascal comment or keyword such as `Project` or `Unit`.

Answer (score 3):

Fileinfo is not using the extension of the file to determine which mime-type it is, but *([quoting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.fileinfo.php))* :

> The functions in this module **try to
> guess the content type** and encoding
> of a file by **looking for certain
> magic byte sequences at specific
> positions** within the file.

The idea being that the name à of the file, and its extension, are provided by the users *(especially in a case such as yours, where the files are being uploaded by users)*, and, as such, are less "sure" than the content of the file itself.

Maybe a solution could be to not check on the whole mime-type returned by fileinfo, but to only use the first part of it -- at least in some cases ?

For instance, maybe you could accept all mimetype that are in the `text/*` and `image/*` families, and refuse all those look like `application/*`, except for `application/pdf` ?

*(Just an example -- but you see the point)*

Answer (score 3):

I have found that, as of at least version 5.03, the '[file](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/)' command can in some circumstances mis-identify a plain text file as a Pascal source file, simply because it contains the word 'program' or 'record'. At least that's how it looks having examined the source (src/names.h). I believe the php fileinfo command uses the same 'magic' engine, so I suspect this is the cause of the problem. If/when I am accepted on the file mailing list, I will notify the maintainers of this issue.

**[UPDATE]**
I asked the question, but got little in the way of a response. Having investigated this issue a bit more throughly, it turns out that [identifying text formats is, in general, really difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet). If you get a 'text/*' MIME type back from file, you might want to consider ignoring the result and assuming the resource is just 'text/plain', unless the false negatives (text/html maybe) will cause you difficulties.

Answer (score 2):

There is a chart that shows a list of common MIME types and their corresponding extensions.
[Here](https://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types-list/)

Comment: Thank you very much Sinan. Going there now.

Comment: On that link that you gave, for example, text/pascal is associated with the .pas extension. In my case, a plain text file is being interpreted as text/pascal for some weird reason.