# Codeigniter not allowing to upload the text file which contains the word 'program'

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-2

CI version 2.1.4

I have created a file upload section in CI version 2.1.4 for text files. That is working fine for all normal text files. But if am trying to upload the text file which contains the word "program" unfortunately CI file validation showing unsupported file format. I tried to print the file type after adding the word "Program" but it is same as earlier(text/plain). I googled also but not getting any solution.

Please help me on this.

**Config Variable**

```
$config['allowed_attachment_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|doc|docx|xlsx|word|xls|csv|txt|text';
```

**Controller upload section**

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file')){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('growl_success', $this->upload->display_errors());
    redirect('/common/lists/edit/'.$id,'refresh');

} else {
    $uploaded = $this->upload->data();

    $data_attachment['id_list']     = $this->input->post('id_list');
    $data_attachment['filename']    = $uploaded['file_name'];
    $data_attachment['title']       = $this->input->post('attachment_title');
    $data_attachment['description'] = $this->input->post('attachment_description');
    $data_attachment['public_yn']   = $this->input->post('public_yn');
    $data_attachment['created_by']  = $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id;
    $data_attachment['modified_by'] = $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id;

    $this->attachment->update_attachment($this->input->post('id_attachment'),$data_attachment);
        redirect('/common/lists/edit/'.$id_list,'refresh');
}
```

Comment: show us your code? Its easier than predicting your code

Comment: Possible to add some code here?

Comment: I have updated the question with code.

Comment: Is that same file being uploaded without `Program` word?

Comment: @poonam Yes. with out that program word it is working. I created a text file with word program and tried. Then also it is not working.

Comment: please change the `$config['allowed_attachment_types'] to $config['allowed_types']` because there is no such config variable like **allowed_attachment_types** in file upload class.

Comment: @RajJagani I have created a new config for attachment section and assigned that to actual config.
 $config['allowed_types'] = $this->config->item('allowed_attachment_types');

If I am changing the wording (program) to anything else that file is uploading.

Comment: This is the answer for my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345899/fileinfo-and-mime-types-ive-never-heard-of

We can add 'text/x-pascal' as file type

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use -

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|doc|docx|xlsx|word|xls|csv|txt|text';
```

instead of -

```
$config['allowed_attachment_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|doc|docx|xlsx|word|xls|csv|txt|text';
```

please try this

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding 'text/x-pascal' type in the condition.