# Programming language detection in PHP

Tags: php

I need to detect which programming language is used in a code snippet, there is any library to do this?

I already read this [Detecting programming language from a snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippe), but I rather use a tested and working library.

Answer (score 2):

The link you posted is exactly what you need. That's only a couple hours of programming time. Otherwise, try googling for "bayesian spam filtering php" - the first result may be what you're looking for: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4236.html

Comment: I just wanted to know if it already exists before starting to code, because I'm short of time. I guess I'll have to do it.