# Identifying keywords of a (programming) language

Tags: c++, perl, text-processing, language-recognition

this is a follow up to my recent question ( [Code for identifying programming language in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600222/code-for-identifying-programming-language-in-a-text-file) ). I'm really thankful for all the answers I got, it helped me very much. **My code for this task is complete and it works fairly well - quick and reasonably accurate.**

*The method i used is the following: i have a "learning" perl script that identifies most frequently used words in a language by doing a word histogram over a set of sample files. These data are then loaded by the c++ program which then checks the given text and accumulates score for each language based on found words and then simply checks which language accumulated the highest score.*

Now i would like to make it even better and work a bit on the quality of identification. **The problem is I often get "unknown" as result** (many languages accumulate a small score, but none anything bigger than my threshold). After some debugging, research etc i found out that this is probably due to the fact, that all words are considered equal. This means that seeing a "#include" for example has the same effect as seeing a "while" - both of which indicate that it might be c/c++ (i'm now ignoring the fact that "while" is used in many other languages), but of course in larger .cpp files there might be a ton of "while" but most of the time only a few "#include".

**So the fact that a "#include" is more important is ignored, because i could not come up with a good way how to identify if a word is more important than another.** Now bear in mind that the script which creates the data is fairly stupid, its only a word histogram and for every chosen word it assigns a score of 1. It does not even look at the words (so if there is a "#&|?/" in a file very often it might get chosen as a good word).

Also i would like to have the data creation part fully automated, so nobody should have to look at the data and alter them, change scores, change words etc. All the "brainz" should be in the script and the cpp program.

**Does somebody have a suggestion how to identify keywords, or more generally, important words?** Some things that might help: i have the number of occurences of each word and the number of total words (so a ratio may be calculated). I have also thought about wiping out characters like ;, etc. since the histogram script often puts for example "continue;" in the result, but the important word is "continue". Last note: all checks for equality are done for exact match - no substrings, case sensitive. This is mainly because of speed, but substrings might help (or hurt, i dont know)...

**NOTE: thanks all who bothered to answer, you helped me a lot.**

My work with this is almost finished so i will describe what i did to get good results.

1) Get a decent training set, about 30-50 files per language from various sources to avoid coding style bias 
2) Write a perl script that does a word histogram. Implement blacklist and whitelist (more about it below)
3) add bogus words to blacklist, like "license", "the" etc. These are often found at the start of file in license information.
4) add about five most important words per language to the whitelist. These are words that are found in most source code of a given language, but are not frequent enough to get into the histogram. For example for C/C++ i had: #include, #define, #ifdef, #ifndef and #endif in the whitelist. 
5) Emphasize the start of a file, so give more points to words found in the first 50-100 lines
6) when doing the word histogram, tokenize the file using `@words = split(/[\s\(\){}\[\];.,=]+/, $_);` This should be ok for most languages i think (gives me the best results). For each language, have about 10-20 most frequent words in the final results.
7) When the histogram is complete, remove all words that are found in the blacklist and add all those that are found in the whitelist 
8) Write a program which processes a text file in the same way as the script - tokenize using the same rules. If a word is found in the histogram data, add points to the right language. Words in the histogram which correspond to only one language should add more points, those which belong to multiple languages should add less.

Comments are welcome. Currently on about 1000 text files i get 80 unknowns (mostly on extremely short files - mainly javascript with just one or two lines). About 20 files are recognized wrong. Size of the files is about 11kB ranging from 100 bytes to 100 kBytes (almost 11MB total). It takes one second to process them all, which is good enough for me.

Comment: I'm positive I've worked with at least one language where "the" was a keyword with a real meaning.  I'm not remembering it now.  Hypertalk, maybe?  Some even more obscure niche language?

Comment: @David Thornley: nothing is perfect, i know. The thing is, that very frequent words like "the" are better ignored, since they bias the detection - comment in english are too common (and license information too). Unique language keywords are much better than words used across a wide variety of languages (if, for, while are really useless).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're approaching this from the wrong viewpoint. From your description, it sounds like you are building a *classifier*. A good classifier needs to discriminate between different classes; it doesn't need to precisely estimate the correspondence between the input and the most likely class.

Practically: your classifier doesn't need to assess precisely how close to C++ a certain input is; it merely needs to determine if the input is more like C than C++. This makes your work a lot easier - most of your current "unknown" cases will be close to one or two languages, even though they don't exceed your basic threshold.

Now, once you realize this, you will also see what training your classifier needs: not some random aspect of the sample files, but what sets two languages apart. Hence, when you have parsed your C samples, and your C++ samples, you will see that `#include` does not set them apart. However, `class` and `template` will be far more common in C++. On the other hand, `#include` *does* distinguish between C++ and Java.

There are of course other aspects besides keywords that you can use. For instance, the most obvious would be the frequency of `{`, and `;` is similarly distinguishing. Another very useful feature for your classifier would be the comment tokens for the different languages. The basic problem of course would be automatically identifying them. Again, hardcoding `//`, `/*`, `'`, `--`, `#` and `!` as pseudo-keywords would help.

This also identifies another classification rule: SQL will often have `--` at the beginning of a line, whereas in C it will often appear somewhere else. Thus it may be useful for your classifier to take the context into account as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Code Search to learn weights for the set of keywords: #include in C++ gets 672.000 hits, in Python only ~5000.

You can normalize the results by looking at the number of results for the language in total:
C++ gives about 770.000 files whereas Python returns 120.000.

Thus "#include" is extremely rare in Python files, but exists in almost every C++ file. (Now you still have to learn to distinguish C++ and C of course.) All that is left is to do the correct reasoning about probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get some exclusiveness into your lookup data.
When teaching the programming languages you expect, you should search for words typical for one or few language(s). If a word appears in several code files of the same language but appears in few or none of the other language files, it's a strong suggestion to that language.
So the score of a word could be calculated at the lookup side by selecting the words that are exclusive to a language or a group of languages. Find several of these words and get the intersection of these by adding the scores, and found your language you will have.

Answer (score 0):

In an answer to your other question, someone recommended a [naïve Bayes classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier). You should implement this suggestion because the technique is good at separating according to distinguishing features. You mentioned the `while` keyword, but that's not likely to be useful because so many languages use it—and a Bayes classifier won't treat it as useful.

An interesting part of your problem is how to tokenize an unknown program. Whitespace-separated chunks is a decent rough start, but going meaningfully beyond that will be tricky.

Comment: Well, comments are one of the ways which help identifying a language. Not the comment itself of course, but the "keyword" used to tell the compiler its a comment.