# How to reliably detect file types?

Tags: java, algorithm, file-type

Objective: given the file, determine whether it is of a given type (XML, JSON, Properties etc)

Consider the case of XML - Up until we ran into this issue, the following sample approach worked fine:

```
    try {
        saxReader.read(f);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        logger.warn("  - File is not XML: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

As expected, when XML is well formed, the test would pass and method would return true. If something bad happens and file can't be parsed, false will be returned.

This breaks however when we deal with a malformed XML (still XML though) file.

I'd rather not rely on `.xml` extension (fails all the time), looking for `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` string inside the file etc.

Is there another way this can be handled?

What would you have to see inside the file to "suspect it may be XML though `DocumentException` was caught". This is needed for parsing purposes.

Comment: Kinda related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600222/code-for-identifying-programming-language-in-a-text-file

Comment: You can't get a definitive answer to "what kind of file is it?", only to "can I pretend it is of type X?" (the answer can be "yes" to zero or more X's, not just zero or one). But you can throw in statistics and see if there are many of `<\w+>` (probably XML), many `"\w+"` (probably JSON) compared to the total number of tokens and otherwise it could be properties.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

File type detection tools:

- [Mime Type Detection Utility](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/)
- [DROID (Digital Record Object Identification)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/droid/)
- [ftc - File Type Classifier](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftclassifier/)
- [JHOVE](http://hul.harvard.edu/jhove/), [JHOVE2](https://bitbucket.org/jhove2/main/wiki/Home)
- [NLNZ Metadata Extraction Tool](http://meta-extractor.sourceforge.net/)
- [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/)
- [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html), [TrIDNet](http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html)
- [Oracle Outside In](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/webcenter/content/oit-all-085236.html) (commercial)
- [Forensic Innovations File Investigator TOOLS](http://www.forensicinnovations.com/fitools.html) (commercial)

Answer (score 10):

[Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) gives me the least amount of issues and is not platform specific unlike Java 7 : [Files.probeContentType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.activation.MimeType;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;

File inputFile = ...
String type = new Tika().detect(inputFile);
System.out.println(type);
```

For a xml file I got 'application/xml'

for a properties file I got 'text/plain'

You can however add a Detector to the new Tika()

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.xx</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who do not need very precise detection (the  **Java 7's Files.probeContentType** method mentioned by rjdkolb)

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("/path/to/your/file.jpg");
String contentType = Files.probeContentType(filePath);
```

Comment: Hi,In win7 64-bit, using jdk1.8, the above method returns null for all file types.Is this an openjdk bug as mentioned in these places - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8080369

Comment: This also breaks on some MAC OS versions, Amazon Correto 8 Java etc.
I don't recommend using it.

Comment: It worth mention that default implementation may just analyze file extension, and fail if the extension is absent. In OpenJDK 16, this is done in sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileTypeDetector. IMO, this could not be considered as reliable file type detection