# parsing a file with a strange extension type using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to parse files with different extension types in my Java program.
I just got a strange file which has a unique file format as below.

> 20121126.033111.vikeng8.28088

I am not sure what is the extension of this particular file. Windows shows type as **28088 File**.
I think its some kind of a text file. I was not able to find any further information from Google. I can open it in Notepad++ and Notepad.

How can I determine this file extension type from Java? What would be the extension in general for these kind of files?

Further, I need to open this file and read some information from it.
Any help would be very useful as i am seeing this kind of strange file for the first time.

Comment: When in doubt, try to open it as text and see if the data appears sane.

Comment: Note, extensions don't necessarily have *anything* to do with file types.  Don't rely on them except maybe as a hint of what format to try first.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738597/how-to-reliably-detect-file-types

Comment: Please don't close the question without the authors consent. Some questions may sound trival to some body but baffling to others.

Answer (score 1):

The extension doesn't necessarily mean anything - for example, putting a .txt extension on a .jpg file doesn't mean it is no longer a .jpg - the file type is generally determined by the contents; the extension is supposed to be a clue to what the contents are.

Regards to your question - the extension on this file is indeed .28088 - though that gives no indication at all of the contents. Java wouldn't be able to tell you anything different.

Comment: Thanks Chris. In my Java code i am determining extension types of files and doing some processing. Example: .zip(some process), .gz(some process), .txt(Some process) etc etc. How do i handle the above kind of particular extension types using Java. I cannot check for numbers right which would be practically impossible as numbers will vary every time. I hope you got my problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**File extensions are not reliable**.

That is just the Windows version of doing things, but obviously file names can be changed. So it is **up to the user to give the files a sensible name**, unfortunately.

Unix has libraries for detecting the type of a file. For example the command `file example.cc` will output something like `C++ source, ASCII text, with very long lines`.

I'd assume it is a single email message or something like this, which you can then treat as an `mbox` file.

Nevertheless, **if you aren't sure about the file extension, assume it is incorrect** and perform proper file type detection.

See e.g.: [How to reliably detect file types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738597/how-to-reliably-detect-file-types)