# How to detect a file category in Java

Tags: java, file, javafx

I was wondering if there is a simple way in Java to know which category of file a file can be (video, audio, document, simple text, ...).

I have tried to know by looking the extension, but I think there is an easier way, is it ??

I'm looking forward for your comment.

Comment: https://odoepner.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/transparently-improve-java-7-mime-type-recognition-with-apache-tika/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a native package from java called `java.nio.file.spi` can do this for you ! As per the documentation, it will guess the type of the file by two ways by extensions and by examining the bytes.
Have a look to the documentation : [Official docs for File Type Detector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html)

As per the discussion in the comment, I am enhancing this answer with this superb next step : [Take a look in this segment : ( probeContentType >>)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-)

```
public static String probeContentType(Path path)
                           throws IOException
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped a lot !!

Comment: The proper way to use this is not to use the spi package.  The only way anyone should be using this is with the [Files.probeContentType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-) method (to which  that spi documentation links, fortunately).

Comment: Yes ! You are right. But I have told the native and first step into it. There can be so many use cases for that and probeContentType is definitely helpful. Thanks @VGR

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [How to reliably detect file types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738597/how-to-reliably-detect-file-types) (especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9742083/3227787)).

I would suggest you to study if it your need allows the usage of [Java's FileTypeDetector class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html).