# CodeMirror - language auto-detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting, codemirror

I'm using stand-alone highlighting (not the editor), something like this:
http://codemirror.net/demo/runmode.html

How can I auto-detect the language to use when running the highlighter?

There's a mode-autochanging demo here:
http://codemirror.net/demo/changemode.html

But I don't know how could I adapt this to work with Codemirror.runMode().  I wish to highlight the entire code block using the auto-detected scheme.

Answer (score 4):

The "changemode" demo can only distinguish between the "Scheme" programming language and "everything else", see the implementation of

```
function looksLikeScheme(code) {
    return !/^\s*\(\s*function\b/.test(code) && /^\s*[;\(]/.test(code);
}
```

So this won't work to auto-detect other programming languages, and as the demo pages says, even for detecting Scheme it's very crude.

Unfortunately, it's not easy to auto-detect a large range of programming languages from a source code snippet (for small snippets, different programming languages might even use the exact same syntax). However, a reasonable approach is suggested in [Detecting programming language from a snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet).