# How to detect programming language from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for a way to test a particular string to determine if it contains code.

For instance, I would like to pass a string such as "body{font-weight: bold;}" and determine that it is CSS.

I would like to do it for:

HTML,
CSS,
JavaScript,
Ruby,
C,C++,C#

I am guessing that it would be regex of some sort, but I am pretty stumped!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting programming language from a snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet)

Comment: `suggest "this is hard"`, especially for Ruby...

Comment: Use python and regex, or just read the file extension.... lol

Comment: @Relic: regex alone is not very powerful.

Comment: @Blender In-fact it's not always even fully effective, I agree. But you got a better idea with a 'string'?

Comment: See my duplicate answer flag ;) You can do a lot with just a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need some kind of a classifier that uses a heurisitic/statistical approach. The accuracy will be better if the input string is larger (e.g. it's hard to say what language `=` belongs to).

Here's an example of a classifier that uses bayesian methods - http://www.rubyinside.com/sourceclassifier-identifying-programming-languages-quickly-1431.html

The [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/) script does detection in javascript. Take a look at the source.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that highlight.js auto detects the language!