# CLI language detection

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using CodeDom compiler to dynamically compile user defined scripts. We're working with C# scripts as  standard, but I was wondering if there was a way how to support all CLI languages. To do that I'd have to detect used CLI language that was used in this particular source code.

Is there some elegant way how to detect only CLI languages from the source code?

Thanks

Comment: There are an awful lot of CLI languages. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages

Comment: Why do you have to detect it from the source code, rather than getting this information from somewhere else? This really is nothing I'd let a program guess.

Comment: Sure, getting this information is of course an option. I was just wondering if there's some hidden .NET  functionality I've never heard of. I think it is reasonable to restrict the languages to only the ones supported by CodeDOM (C#, Visual Basic, C++, J#, and JScript).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting programming language from a snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet)

Comment: @user436730: "only CLI languages" and "only languages support by CodeDOM" are two extremely different (though overlapping) sets of languages. Which one are you actually looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There are only 3 languages for which the framework provides a CodeDomProvider: C#, JScript and VB. Therefore, if the framework provides any direct method to parse "any language", it can only support these 3 languages. I don't think it does.

You may want to try to parse your code with all three implementations of CodeDomProvider, and keep the first that succeeds. It will take a dozen of lines of code.

I think it might be your best try.

Documentation for CodeDomProvider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds075xdx.aspx
Documentation for CodeDomProvider.Parse: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx