# Text processing - Identify code syntax

Tags: java, javascript

Is there a Java or Javascript library that can be used to identify a given text (even partially) if what code syntax the text is. Example, to identify if the text is a Java code, Javascript code, etc.

Doesn't have to be too accurate, as it will be used for user suggestion.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None yet. Create one.

Java libraries:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Javascript libraries:

https://www.javascripting.com/