# Automatically detect the programming language of given script in python

Tags: python

I have a python script that reads in a file, should then detect the language of the code in the file, get the language ID from https://ghostbin.com/languages.json and upload it to https://ghostbin.com with the language ID as a parameter.
The problem is detecting the programming language used. I haven't found any lib to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a module](https://github.com/glaslos/langdog) that uses a Naive Bayes classifier to do what you want, with [a corresponding discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet). The caveat is that the module needs to be trained on code samples. It should be easy enough to modify it to retain its training.