# Check if text is C# Code in C#

Tags: c#

In my C# Winforms application I have a textbox where the user can enter text. Is there any method/any criteria to check if the entered code is a C# code?

Comment: This post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CSharpCodeProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) to compile the input text.
If it built successfully, it's c# code.

Comment: I only want to know if its code, not if its right code

Comment: @VerbxteneSkillz How do you want to distinguish between invalid code and random text? Any common word could be a class, field or property. I think compiling or checking the whole syntax yourself (and I do not recommend to do that) are the only options