# How to validate javascript content in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In my form, I have a text area. The textarea has to allow only javascript content. I have to validate the text area content, to check if it is javascript or not. How to check if the Text area contains data that is only valid javascript content?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I have a form , which allows choosing  a file of type js and allows to write jscode in textarea,how can i validate written jscode in textarea?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet

Comment: If you want to validate the code of textarea you can do that by embedding eslint as a script. See https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JavaScript parser like [`acorn`](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) and check whether you can correctly parse the textarea contents.

The snippet below uses `acorn` to try and parse the contents of two textareas, one containing valid JavaScript, and one just containing plain text.

```js
function validateJs(textareaId) {
  const textarea = document.getElementById(textareaId);
  
  try {
    acorn.Parser.parse(textarea.value);
  } catch(e) {
    textarea.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    return false;
  }
  
  textarea.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  return true;
}

validateJs('good');
validateJs('bad');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/acorn/6.1.1/acorn.js"></script>

<textarea id="good" rows="4" cols="25">
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
</textarea>

<textarea id="bad" rows="4" cols="25">
Hello world!
</textarea>
```

Comment: Used acorn.Parser.parse(textarea.value) and installed acron using npm i acron, but it shows error

Comment: Usage as a module is different. Refer to the source code/documentation on the GitHub page.