# Creating a check SQL check constraint to validate that an NVARCHAR column contains valid SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl, check-constraints

I'm attempting to write a check constraint on an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column in my database. This column will be filled with SQL, and I want to make sure that it is only populated with SQL. Is it possible to write a check constraint to make sure that this column is only populated with SQL?

Comment: The best way to verify the validity of SQL is to not reinvent mechanisms that the database already has for storing SQL - e.g. views, stored procedures, etc.

Comment: The only way to manipulate data in a table is to use SQL (insert, update, delete). So "*that it is only populated with SQL*" makes no sense, as there is no other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're essentially looking for is language detection - instead of using it to filter things *out* (e.g., like mail clients who tell you things like "OMG THIS IS CODE DO NOT CLICK ON THE ATTACHMENT"), you want to filter things *in*.  There's a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475033/detecting-programming-language-from-a-snippet) with an excellent answer by @Michael Myers.  A helpful soul (@nisc) also linked to how Github does lang detection [here](https://github.com/github/linguist).